# How to know if Zephyr for JIRA server is installed in JIRA server instance through REST API?

Tags: jira-rest-api, jira-zephyr

I would like to know if there exists any REST API that returns the details of installed plugins of a JIRA server instance or more specifically my requirement is to know if Zephyr for JIRA server is installed in a particular JIRA server instance.

I am using JIRA Server 7.5.2 and its compatible Zephyr plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the required access / permissions to your user id with which you login to JIRA of if you have the administrative rights on JIRA for your Organization, then the following should work.

Follow the API documentation [here](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/UPM/UPM+REST+API).

```
curl $BASE_URL/rest/plugins/1.0/

Usage:
curl -D- -u username:userpassword -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://<BASE_URL>/rest/plugins/1.0/
```

The command above will give you all plugins that are installed. You can then further filter on the list of plugins that are installed by users using the `userInstalled` key, e.g. with jq:

```
curl $BASE_URL/rest/plugins/1.0/ | jq ".plugins | map(select(.userInstalled))"
```

Hope this helps!